# Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'metrics'

Tags: r, keras

A code example from the book ["Deep Learning with R", Advanced usage of recurrent neural networks - A basic machine learning approach]

The code could be found in Github:
https://jjallaire.github.io/deep-learning-with-r-notebooks/notebooks/6.3-advanced-usage-of-recurrent-neural-networks.nb.html

I try to run this code:

```
history <- model %>% fit_generator(
train_gen,
steps_per_epoch = 500,
epochs = 20,
validation_data = val_gen,
validation_steps = (9000-6001-36)/128
)
```

And get this error-message:

> Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'metrics'

Could someone tell me what does it mean and how can man fit it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you Sotos :)

Comment: I tried to run it again, and there is one more error: Error occurred in generator: argument 'length.out' must be of length 1

Answer (score 1):

When you compile your model, specify the metrics using string, and not array. Like this:

```
modelo %>% compile(
  loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
  metrics = 'accuracy'
)
```

If you do something like this: metrics = c('accuracy') it will not work.